# How do I get the last 5 rows of a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, take

How do I get the last 5 rows of a datatable? I tried something like this:

```
var Long_bottom = LongSlection.Last(5);
```

Where LongSlection is a DataRow. But I had an error, any idea?

Comment: if `LongSlection` is a `DataRow` how do you expect it to return you 2 rows ? I think you need to add bit more details to the question

Comment: if you do a             var Long_top = LongSlection.Take(15); you have the first 15 rows of the datarows, I don't see why it cannot work for the bottom

Comment: @francopshenri: How about my answer?

Comment: maybe you can do `.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(5);`

Comment: @V4Vendetta Wthz with the magic number 5, when the OP asks for 2? :-P

Comment: @Vijay Well the title says so :)

Comment: @V4Vendetta, Well then poop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you have got here

> var Long_bottom = LongSlection.Last(5);

Assuming you have a DataTable and you want to get the last 5 rows you can do that via

```
datatable1.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(5);
```

`Take` and `Skip` return the specific number of elments (parameter is int) while which is not the case with `Last` you get the last element or you need a predicate for checking conditions or checks within the row.

Answer (score 0):

This SHOULD do it. but it's untested!

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> lastRows = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(table.Rows.Count - 2).ToList();
```

Or:

```
table.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(2);
```

Edit: Modified to get the last TWO, as per the OPs request.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Datarow[] dr = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(dt.Rows.Count - 5).ToArray();
```

**OR**

```
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Reverse().Take(5);
```

Here 5 is the last number of rows to take.

Answer (score 0):

I needed [`CopyToDataTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.8) to get things done:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(5).CopyToDataTable();
```